# Reading data in R from package

Tags: r

I'm studying from a book called "Introductory Statistics in R" which uses data from the package "ISwR".My problem is that I can't load the data on the workspace.When I do

```
install.packages("ISwR");
library(ISwR)
ls()
data(ISwR)
```

I get nothing.What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can see ISwR does not have a data set called ISwR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISwR` is the name of the *package*, not the datasets included in the package.

You can use `data(package = "ISwR")` to see the list of datasets which come with the *Introductory Statistics in R* package.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("ISLR")  #install the package ISLR

library(ISLR)

data(package = "ISLR")  #list the datasets in the package ISLR

car=as.data.frame(Auto)  #read the dataset Auto in the package ISLR

car
```